# How to re-order table row numbers when rows are added and removed

Tags: javascript

I am dynamically generating table rows using javascript (no jquery involved). Each row has 3 cells zone number, input, and a delete button. The number of rows added uses a select box to if they select 3, 3 rows are added ect. What I want to happen is if they add 3 rows then add another 3. the rows will be will displayed as 1,2,3,4,5,6, Currently its 1,2,3,1,2,3. I also what to re-order the rows when a row is deleted.

Current code php file:

```
   function display_Zones($focus, $field, $value, $view){

    global $locale, $app_list_strings, $mod_strings;

    $html = '';

    if($view == 'EditView'){

        $html .= '<script src="modules/dry_Zones/zone_items.js"></script>';
        $html .= "<div style='padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom:10px;'>";
        $html .= "<select id='zone' name='zone'>";
        $html .= get_select_options_with_id($app_list_strings["zone_list"]);
        $html .= "</select> ";

        $html .= "<input type=\"button\" tabindex=\"116\" class=\"button\" value=\"addZone\" id=\"addZone\" onclick=\"insertZone()\" />";
        $html .= "</div>";

        $html .= "<table border='0' cellspacing='4' width='40%' id='zoneItems'>";
        $html .= "<tr><td></td><td>Motor Reference Point</td><td></td></tr>";

        $html .= "</table>";



        return $html;
    }
```

javascript file:

```
 var num = 1;

 function insertZone() {

var table = document.getElementById('zoneItems');

var e = document.getElementById('zone');
var number = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

if(number != ''){


    for (var i=0; i < number; i++)
    {
        var x = table.insertRow(-1);
        var a = x.insertCell(0);
        num = num+i;

        a.innerHTML = "<span>Zone: "+num+"</span> ";

        var b = x.insertCell(1);
        b.innerHTML = "<input type='text' name='motor_ref_point' size='18' value='' />";

        var c = x.insertCell(2);
        c.innerHTML = "<button class='button lastChild' onclick='removeZone(this)' ><img src='themes/default/images/id-ff-clear.png'></button>";
    }


}
```

}

```
  function removeZone(rows) {

  var _row = rows.parentElement.parentElement;
  document.getElementById('zoneItems').deleteRow(_row.rowIndex);



   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the most efficient, way, but I don't think you'll notice any problems unless you have thousands of rows.  When you add/delete rows, you could just iterate through the first table cell of each row and update it based on the index.

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('td:first-child'),
function (elem, idx) {
    elem.innerHTML = idx + 1;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/2QxX6/

Comment: +1; I was about to type out an answer with the same thing in it.

Comment: Call that after `insertZone` and `removeZone`

Comment: there is more than 1 table on this page, its part of a ui. calling that just blanks the page and displays 1

Comment: @user794846 you can use a more specific selector, like `'#zoneItems td:first-child'`.  Not to be mean, but I'm sure you can figure out *some* things for yourself

Comment: im not I answered my own question below. Just done it the long winded way.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up just doing it like this:

```
function insertZone() {

var table = document.getElementById('zoneItems');

var e = document.getElementById('zone');
var number = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

if(number != ''){


    for (var i=0; i < number; i++)
    {
        var x = table.insertRow(-1);
        var a = x.insertCell(0);
        num = i+1;

       // a.innerHTML = "<span>Zone: "+num+"</span> ";

        var b = x.insertCell(1);
        b.innerHTML = "<input type='text' name='motor_ref_point' size='18' value='' />";

        var c = x.insertCell(2);
        c.innerHTML = "<button class='button lastChild' onclick='removeZone(this)' ><img src='themes/default/images/id-ff-clear.png'></button>";
    }

    count();
}
```

}

```
  function removeZone(rows) {

var _row = rows.parentElement.parentElement;
document.getElementById('zoneItems').deleteRow(_row.rowIndex);

count();
}

function count(){

var table = document.getElementById("zoneItems");
var tbody = table.tBodies[0];
row_count = tbody.rows.length - 1;

for (var i = 0, row; row = tbody.rows[i]; i++) {

    if(i != 0){

        for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {

            if(j == 0){
                col.innerHTML = "<span>Zone: "+i+"</span> ";
            }
        }
    }

}

}
```

Comment: what's with the `if (i != 0)`?

Comment: Making sure that its not the first row in the table because that got headings in it.

Comment: In that case the first row should be in `<thead>`, not tbodies, and you should use `<th>` for the columns

Comment: Then ultimately you can use my answer.  It just needs to be updated to `elem.innerHTML = "<span>Zone:" + (idx + 1) + "</span>";`